# RGB to Hex convertation

Tags: javascript, системы-счисления, rgb

Написал функцию, которая конвертирует из RGB в HEX, то есть из десятичной системы, в шестнадцатеричную. Единственная проблема, что при выводе хочу, чтобы отображалось не "000", а "000000", не "FFF", а "FFFFFF" соответственно. Как лучше решить?

```
function rgb(r, g, b){
  let translatedR = r.toString(16);
  let translatedG = g.toString(16);
  let translatedB = b.toString(16);
  let hexTranslation = translatedR + translatedG + translatedB;

   
  return hexTranslation.toUpperCase()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы дополнить строку символами до нужной длины можно применить метод [`.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
function rgb(r, g, b) {
  let translatedR = r.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  let translatedG = g.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  let translatedB = b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
  let hexTranslation = translatedR + translatedG + translatedB;


  return hexTranslation.toUpperCase()
}

console.log(rgb(0, 0, 0))
console.log(rgb(15, 15, 225))
```

Comment: а как же какой нить однострок? ) `return [r,g,b].map(c => c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join()` ? )

Comment: не было цели уменьшить код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ в этом случае можно не разбивать на параметры и сразу `(...args) => args.map(c => c.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join().toUpperCase()` делать